# return every first value in groups of ids and dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve such problem.
I have two DFs:

1. ids, start_date (of subscription), end_date (of subscription), start_ts (equal start_date  + time), end_ts (equal end_date + time);[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stfq3.png)
2. ids, ts_start( date and time of viewing content), title. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfFbw.png)

I need to find all titles, which users watched first in their every new subscription and after count them.
I tried to do it with loop, first df has about 300 thousands strings and second df has over 17 millions strings, so kernel died every time.

Comment: Please add samples of dataframes as code `df.to_dict()` to the question. And also please share the code you have tried even if it didn't totally work. It will help to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Dmitri maybe try doing what Maria said with the head of each dataframe, and replace the passport ids with something else like the string "passport id"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main ideas to this solution:

1. We need a unique identifier for each subscription period. The easiest way is just to use the row number.
2. To assign the correct period to the watch time, we do an over merge just on User ID and then use date comparisons to filter it down to the rows with the correct period

At that point, it's just a matter of using groupby to get the first watched per period ID, re-merge to filter down, and then count the movies.

Since the problem didn't provide a dataframe, I also generated my own:

```
# Random data generation
start_date = np.datetime64("2018-01-01")
end_date = np.datetime64("2023-07-24")
seconds = np.timedelta64(end_date - start_date, "s")

rows = 10000

unique_users = 500
unique_titles = 50
titles = [f"Title_{i}" for i in range(unique_titles)]
max_sub_periods = 10

random_users = random.choices(range(unique_users), k=rows)
random_times = random.choices(start_date + np.arange(seconds), k=rows)
random_titles = random.choices(titles, k=rows)
random_periods = random.choices(range(1, max_sub_periods + 1), k=unique_users)

watch_times = pd.DataFrame(
    {"User ID": random_users, "Start_TS": random_times, "Title": random_titles}
)

first_times = watch_times.groupby("User ID")["Start_TS"].min()
last_times = watch_times.groupby("User ID")["Start_TS"].max()

sub_periods = pd.DataFrame({"User ID": [], "Sub_Start": [], "Sub_End": []})

row_counter = 0

for i in range(unique_users):
    first = first_times.loc[i]
    last = last_times.loc[i]
    periods = random_periods[i]

    lengths = random.sample(
        range(int((last - first) / np.timedelta64(1, "s"))), k=periods - 1
    )

    sub_start = first
    for j in range(len(lengths)):
        sub_periods.loc[row_counter] = [
            i,
            sub_start,
            sub_start + np.timedelta64(lengths[j], "s"),
        ]
        sub_start = sub_periods.loc[row_counter, "Sub_End"]
        row_counter += 1

    sub_periods.loc[row_counter] = [i, sub_start, last]
    row_counter += 1
    
sub_periods["period"] = sub_periods.index
```

Actual solution:

```
over_merge = watch_times.merge(sub_periods, on="User ID")
valid = (over_merge["Sub_Start"] <= over_merge["Start_TS"]) & (
    over_merge["Start_TS"] <= over_merge["Sub_End"]
)

watch_times2 = over_merge[valid]

first_movies = watch_times2.merge(
    watch_times2.groupby(["User ID", "period"])["Start_TS"].min().reset_index(),
    on=["User ID", "period", "Start_TS"],
)

counts = first_movies.groupby('Title').size()
```